# I can't get the WHO_AM_I address from the LIS3DSH accelerometer. SPI. STM32

Tags: stm32, spi, accelerometer

I want to get the `WHO_AM_I` address from the accelerometer [LIS3DSH](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/lis3dsh-954955.pdf), which is located on the [STM32F407VGT6](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet%20/stm32f405rg.pdf) board.

To be more precise, after I press Hardreset many times, I start receiving the `WHO_AM_I` address from the accelerometer.
Receiving a `WHO_AM_I` address with my code is a random event, I don’t know what the pattern is here.

Here's the code I'm using:

The address of the `WHO_AM_I` register is `0x0F`, to read this register, I need to send `0x8F`.

```
uint8_t address=0x8F; //Register address+read
uint8_t result;
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //Chip Select
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,&address,1,1000);
HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1,&result,1,1000);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET); //Chip Select
```

Perhaps the `HAL_SPI_Receive` function does not have time to save the data into the `result` variable because the `HAL_SPI_Transmit` function takes too long to process?

I tried using `CMSIS`, but with `CMSIS` after the line

```
SPI1->DR = address;
```

The `SPI_SR_TXE` bit remains constantly `zero`, which means that the `TX` buffer is full and no data has been transmitted.

After sending the register address `HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,&address,1,1000);` I must immediately get the `WHO_AM_I` address.

Image from [LIS3DSH Datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/lis3dsh-954955.pdf), edited by me.
[image]
But I don't know how to do it correctly.

SPI Baud Rate 5.25 MBit/s.
LIS3DSH operates up to 10 MBit/s.
GPIO Pin Chip Select is enabled.

**Now the wires are connected to the SPI GPIO pins, I need them for the display.
These wires are now connected only on one side to the SPI GPIO pins, they are not currently connected to the display.
When I disconnect these wires, my code starts working and I get a WHO_AM_I address, connect the wires back, do as it was, the code still continues to work and I get a WHO_AM_I address.
I'm doing a Hard Reset.There is no short circuit between the wires.
Maybe at these frequencies my wires create a lossy transmission line?
But why then does the code continue to work if I connect the wires back?**
[image]

Comment: Did you try to run any example provided from the IDE?

Comment: Did you configure CPOL and CPHA according to the needs of the LIS3DSH?

Comment: jusaca,
 Yes.
CPOL==0
CPHA==0
This corresponds to the required parameters for LIS3DSH.
The problem is with the wires I connected, you can see them in the picture.
But I don't understand why this problem occurs because of the wires.

Comment: coal, I need to find out the WHO_AM_I address.
The problem comes from the wires, you can see them in the image.
I don't know why this problem occurs because of the wires.

Comment: While there are several ways how to implement this but recommended is using HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive instead of separate transmit and receive call. Issue is that depending on setting there may be additional edges when transitioning to default clock state. Using single call basicaly prevent them and enables hardware to manage it automaticaly. You need to provide 2x 2-byte buffer. Transmit buffer contains address and zero. Output you get in second item of receive buffer. First item in this buffer will be irelevant. You can also try some basic SPI troubleshoting techniques like reducing speed.